# QGIS "Failed to add field" to PostGIS table

Tags: qgis, postgis

I have just ran into an issue with QGIS/PostGIS. Here is a summary of my problem:

1. I have uploaded a world country boundaries shapefile as a PostGIS table to my database.
2. I add the new PostGIS table to QGIS as a layer.
3. I toggle editing for the table so that I may edit the file.
4. I click on "New Field" and enter "test" as the field name, leaving everything else default.
5. I click "OK" and the following error message pops up: "Failed to add field 'test' of type 'int2'. Is the field name unique?"
6. There is no other field named "test", and no other field name works.

All the googling I have done on SE/SO and this sub have left me empty handed. Does anyone have an idea as to why I cannot add a field to this PostGIS table?

At first I thought it may have been a privilege issue with Postgres but I double checked the login role that I used has insert/update/delete privileges. Additionally, I connected to the database using the superuser credentials and had the same issue.
For reference, I am using QGIS 2.18.9 with Win7 x64.

Also, some additional information: When I toggle editing for the table, the "Delete field" button is still grayed out, which I thought was odd as usually that button is usable when editing is toggled on. Not sure if that's helpful or not.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar situation in QGIS where I could add new features and save them, but adding or deleting new fields weren't possible. It turned our that my logged in user in QGIS had permissions for reading/writing etc, but the **owner** of the table was a different user. Changing ownership of the table in PgAdmin to the QGIS user solved the issue.

Comment: I was facing the same issue, thanks. The QGIS error statement itself is misleading